# How to restore permissions in /usr/lib folder?

Tags: 16.04, permissions

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I accidentally ran the command,

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/lib
```

Then I lost the sudo permssions, but I could get it back. But now WiFi connections are not showing.

Is there any way to restore permissions of this folder to the initial state?

Comment: Restore a backup (using whatever backup procedures you have chosen), although back when I did something similar I booted to a 'live' install media, and using another installed image as a template (though I guess you could use the 'live' itself) had a script change permissions to match the other file-system directory.  If you don't like the scripting option, I'd suggest a re-install (the testing of my script took longer than a re-install I suspect)

Comment: Since you didn't record permissions beforehand, the safest option is to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: I agree with `waltinator`.  But if you install Ubuntu onto another device (be careful in the installer setup) such as a USB memory stick that is big enough (8GB or more) plus install  every package you have added, then you can have `rsync` fix it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed these steps, from [How to Easily Back Up and Restore Linux File Permissions](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-easily-back-and-restore-linux-file-permissions), to get a backup of permissions using another ubuntu system (by booting from a Ubuntu USB image) and then restored it. It works.

To backup permissions:

```
getfacl -R TEST > test_permissions.txt
```

To restore permissions:

```
setfacl --restore=test_permissions.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is not recommended**, but probably what I would have done:

```
$ dpkg -S '/usr/lib/*' | \
  cut -d : -f1 | sed 's/, /\n/g' | sort -u >> dpkg-package.log
```

This creates a package list of all packages that have files in `/usr/lib`, the next step is to sort out locally installed or non-installable packages.

```
$ xargs -a ./dpkg-package.log apt-get --dry-run reinstall
```

If apt-get complains about packages, move them from the dpkg-package.log to dpkg-temp.log. When you are ready to reinstall, just remove the --dry-run option. This will restore the permission on the reinstalled files.

Comment: If as you say all the files are set to 777 you can identify them after with *find -type f, d -ls | less* or *find --type f, d -perm 777 -ls | less*. Normally regular files are 644 and 755 for directories. the hard part will be to identify which files need exec bit.